# SSLconfig.ini in DB2 V105

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We need to change the permission of file `SSLconfig.ini` to 740 as per our requirements. But I have not found that file in `/opt` or `/home/db2inst1`.

Can you please let me know the location of `SSLconfig.ini` file?

Comment: Since V9.7 the file is gone - seen this? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054537.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you should be on a DB2 version of 9.7 or higher, there isn't any `SSLconfig.ini` anymore. The configuration options are now database manager configuration (dbm cfg) parameters. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054537.html for details.

The dbm cfg parameters all start with the prefix `ssl_` and include server-side and client-side parameters. A mapping of the old configuration options to the new dbm cfg parameters is provided in the linked reference.